# Generic Method Type Argument Inference Issue

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I am unable to understand why second invocation below gives compiler error. Why is it not able to infer Number as type argument as in the first invocation?

```
typeArgInference(new Integer[100], new ArrayList<Number>()); // Infers Number

typeArgInference(new Number[100], new ArrayList<Integer>()); // compiler error

<T> void typeArgInference(T[] a, Collection<T> c) {}
```

May be I am missing something here. If there is any rule in JLS on this behavior, please do include the link.

Comment: Do you realise that a `Collection<Integer>` cannot be implicitly converted to a `Collection<Number>`?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The fact that type argument inference could lead to invariance just did not cross my mind. Was always looking at invariance examples involving only non-generic methods. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generics are invariant, arrays are covariant:

- An `Integer[]` can act as a `Number[]` (because `Integer` is a subclass of `Number`)
- An `ArrayList<Integer>` can't act as an `ArrayList<Number>` (because you can add e.g. a `Double` to the latter, but you mustn't add a `Double` into a list of `Integer`s).

Of course, you can try to put a `Double` into a `Number[]`, but it that would fail with `ArrayStoreException` if your `Number[]` is really an `Integer[]`. This would be a runtime failure.

Making arrays covariant was a fudge to have sort-of generic sort-of collections before the language supported generics. It was realized that this was a problem (because runtime failures suck), hence why generics were designed to be invariant.

Since you asked for JLS links:

- [Sec 4.10.2 Subtyping among Class and Interface Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2)
- [Sec 4.10.3 Subtyping among Array Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3)

---

Both of your examples would compile if you added an upper bound to the list type:

```
<T> void typeArgInference(T[] a, Collection<? extends T> c) {}
```

In both cases, `Number` is a type that would satisfy the type constraints:

- `Integer[]` can act as a `Number[]`; and `ArrayList<Number>` is a `Collection<Number>`, which is a `Collection<? extends Number>`.
- `Number[]` can act as a `Number[]` (obviously); and `ArrayList<Integer>` is a `Collection<Integer>`, which is a `Collection<? extends Number>`.

You just then could not add anything into the `Collection` within that method (other than literal `null`; or by breaking type safety via raw types).